# What does the linux make command do?

Tags: linux

I created a database and a table inside it.I insert records manually and then run a python script which reads the records and updates them in the table. I was just trying 
the `make &>1.txt` command to redirect the output when the unexpected happened.
Even when I am not running the script and insert the record manually from mysql, the script is
running somewhere as it updates the records , but I am not running it any tab
What is the reason ??
The script just starts running by itself!!!

Comment: But it is running, if you put it in the background with '&' surely? The command `make` just runs whatever instructions it finds in the file "Makefile", so there's no way for us to know what behaviour you'd expect from your makefile. Why don't you read the manpage first?

Comment: @NicholasWilson I am sorry I not so familiar with this could you elaborate , what I wanted to do was redirect stderr and stdout of my script in a file , not run it in background .Why is the make command only running this script in background why not any other scriptin my current folder??

Comment: Maybe because that's what your makefile tells it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's running in the background (which could have happened if you typed `make & >1.txt` with a space, not what you showed above) then the `jobs` command will show it is running, and `fg` will bring it to the foregound, so you can kill it with `Ctrl-C`

(You can also kill it with the jobspec shown by `jobs` e.g. `kill %1` but if you don't know  what you're doing it's simpler to bring it to the foreground and interrupt it)

Comment: by running fg it does show my script name but Ctrl-C does not work